MQTT bridge_to_target authorization issue
I am trying to run two separate brokers on one linux device.
I setup the two brokers with the following little script (omitted the second one for readability as it is identical except for the ending IoT was changed to HA and the port is 1884):
temp_file=/tmp/mosquittoIoT.conf
cat <<EOF > $temp_file
listener 1883
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/brokerIoT/credentialsIoT

connection bridge_to_target
address 192.168.0.2:1884  # Assuming the target broker is running on port 1884
topic cmnd/# both 0

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
log_type all
EOF
sudo mv $temp_file /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/brokerIoT/mosquittoIoT.conf

temp_file=/tmp/mosquittoIoT.service
cat <<EOF > $temp_file
[Unit]
Description=Mosquitto MQTT Broker IoT

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/brokerIoT/mosquittoIoT.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
sudo mv $temp_file /etc/systemd/system/mosquittoIoT.service

I am trying to sync the cmnd topic and all subtopics between the two brokers but I keep getting the error
1726351450: Sending SUBACK to 65bBPKjODcW8Zcq1BtKjiL
1726351453: Bridge local.piserver.bridge_to_target doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic cmnd/#
1726351453: Connecting bridge (step 1) bridge_to_target (192.168.0.2:1883)
1726351453: Connecting bridge (step 2) bridge_to_target (192.168.0.2:1883)
1726351453: Bridge piserver.bridge_to_target sending CONNECT
1726351453: New connection from 192.168.0.2:58414 on port 1883.
1726351453: Sending CONNACK to 192.168.0.2 (0, 5)
1726351453: Client <unknown> disconnected, not authorised.
1726351453: Received CONNACK on connection local.piserver.bridge_to_target.
1726351453: Connection Refused: not authorised
1726351453: Client local.piserver.bridge_to_target closed its connection.
1726351453: Sending PUBLISH to mqtt-explorer-5de5cf70 (d0, q0, r0, m0, '$SYS/broker/connection/piserver.bridge_to_target/state', ... (1 bytes))
1726351455: Received PUBLISH from 65bBPKjODcW8Zcq1BtKjiL (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'homeassistant/status', ... (6 bytes))
1726351455: Sending PUBLISH to mqtt-explorer-5de5cf70 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'homeassistant/status', ... (6 bytes))
1726351457: Bridge local.piserver.bridge_to_target doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic cmnd/#
1726351457: Connecting bridge (step 1) bridge_to_target (192.168.0.2:1884)
1726351457: Connecting bridge (step 2) bridge_to_target (192.168.0.2:1884)
1726351457: Bridge piserver.bridge_to_target sending CONNECT
1726351457: New connection from 192.168.0.2:52406 on port 1884.
1726351457: Sending CONNACK to 192.168.0.2 (0, 5)
1726351457: Client <unknown> disconnected, not authorised.
1726351457: Received CONNACK on connection local.piserver.bridge_to_target.
1726351457: Connection Refused: not authorised
1726351457: Client local.piserver.bridge_to_target closed its connection.

I do not understand why there would be an authorisation issue. Both brokers use the same user name and password. And I can connect with MQTT Explorer and my device are sending data to both brokers successfully. It only seems to be an issue in the bridge.
Does anybody see what I am doing wrong?
Thank you all
Alex

You need to specify the local_user, local_password, remote_user and remote_password in the configuration file so that the broker knows which credentials to use on both ends of the bridge.
Also it's not 100% clear in the question, but the second broker's config should not include the bridge in the other direction, since you are using the both keyword, messages will travel back and forth with a single bridge.
